How to make whole immersive view visible all the time, when having multiple immersive views on Android TV using Jetpack Compose?
I work on Android TV app using Jetpack Compose. I follow the Guide and I want to make a page with multiple immersive views. I also want to be able to change focus from one to other immersive view and change focus inside of immersive view, while is whole focused immersive view visible.
Each immersive view consists of Box and LazyRow, just like in guide example - let's call immersive view SampleImmersiveList. My Box also has           bringIntoViewRequester on his modifier.
In next step, I made LazyColumn whose items are SampleImmersiveList.
When is focused Item from LazyRow, that means I want the whole belonging SampleImmersiveList to be visible. To achive that, I use:
coroutineScope.launch { bringIntoViewRequester.bringIntoView() }

It works if I use buttons up and down on remote controller - going from one SampleImmersiveList to another SampleImmersiveList.
But when I use buttons left and right - changing focus in LazyRow (in one SampleImmersiveList) - it doesn't work as expected.

When is focused 1st item of LazyRow, bringIntoView works - whole SampleImmersiveList is visible and LazyRow is in the bottom of the screen
When is focused 2nd item of LazyRow, bringIntoView doesn't work - LazyRow is in the center of the screen is and upper part of SampleImmersiveList is not visible
When is focused 3rd item of LazyRow, bringIntoView works - whole SampleImmersiveList is visible and LazyRow is in the bottom of the screen
When is focused 4th item of LazyRow, bringIntoView doesn't work - LazyRow is in the center of the screen is and upper part of SampleImmersiveList is not visible
When is focused 5th item of LazyRow, bringIntoView works - whole SampleImmersiveList is visible and LazyRow is in the bottom of the screen
When is focused 6th item of LazyRow, bringIntoView doesn't work - LazyRow is in the center of the screen is and upper part of SampleImmersiveList is not visible
...

How to make whole immersive view visible all the time?
